# Can Objective-C's new literal syntax mimic the addObject?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-literals

I know that I can do this to :

```
NSMutableArray *objects = [@[objectOne, objectTwo] mutableCopy];
NSObject *someObject = [NSObject new];
objects[0] = someObject;
```

But is there a way for the new literal syntax to mimic addObject:?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I was writing this, I tried out this bit of code and it worked like a charm. It isn't exactly documented, but I think this is a safe way to handle addObject: with the new literal syntax.

```
NSMutableArray *objects = [@[] mutableCopy];
NSObject *someObject = [NSObject new];
objects[objects.count] = object;
```

Comment: It actually is documented to do this way in the setObject:atIndexedSubscript: method

Comment: "If the index is equal to count the element is added to the end of the array, growing the array."

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this?

Comment: For science, that's why.

Comment: That, and the possibility of re-setting, then adding elements to an array  in a loop without doing a bounds check :) Nice.

Comment: Would be good to have a objects[] = object, please add it Apple! :D